# Meaning of `printf("%0*lld",k,r);`

Tags: c

I saw this code somewhere

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long long k=1,r=4;
    printf("%0*lld",k,r);
}
```

What is the meaning of `%0*lld` and how are two variables used in this when we have one format specifier?

Comment: Take time to read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) man page (or type `man 3 printf` on Unix systems).

Comment: I would have thought that `k`  should be `int`, as `*` stands for taking the number width as parameter. _(`0` for zero-padded, `lld` for `long long int`.)_

Comment: @JoopEggen: `k` should be `int`. I think the code as presented is technically undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

k becomes the precision.

as in:

```
printf("%01lld",r);
```

and to digest that a little bit further...

`%lld` is the format specifier for `long long`

`%01(something)` means that it is zero padded, with min width of 1.

[here is a hard to digest reference...](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)
and some [examples](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).

Comment: And `k` is converted to `int`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch good point, could be wrong on 32 bit big endian.

Comment: No, `k` will not be implicitly converted to `int`. It should be converted explicitly, or defined as `int` in the first place.

Comment: that is what I mean it could break magnificently, I needs to be cast, as you could have both the offset and the first 32 bits of the formatted value taken from k.. depending on abi and alignment options